# Getting Windows 11 Live Tiles to work again

Tags: windows, windows-10, modern-ui, windows-11, windows-11-preview

I've installed the Windows 10 Developer preview that has the Windows 11 UI changes.  I don't like them.  They look like a bad version of the MacOS instead of the Windows Live Tiles.  I followed the instructions [here](https://www.windowslatest.com/2021/06/16/live-tiles-can-be-re-enabled-in-windows-11-if-you-really-love-them/) to get the Windows Live Tiles back.  I wasn't sure if I should create a 32 bit or 86 bit DWord, so I created a 32 bit version.

It worked for a while, however there was another system upgrade and my live tiles are gone again.  I've noticed there's a

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\StartMode]
"ActualStartMode"=dword:00000001
```

in Windows 10 Developer Preview machine's Registry that's not in my work computer.  Can I change this setting to get my Live Tiles back.

Comment: The key you attempted to use was disabled in the most recent build of Windows 11.  What you want is not possible.  My advice is to downgrade to Windows 10.

Comment: Is it possible?  I  didn't think you could roll back from insider program.

Comment: It's possible for 10 days. Downgrade includes performing a clean install of Windows 10. There is a reason Windows 11 isn't yet recommended as a daily driver. If it's been less than that amount of time, and you have not installed any updates, you can use `DISM /Online /Set-OS-UninstallWindow /Value:30` to increase the window.  However, once you install the next build, you will lose that ability.

Comment: There was a new build just recently, so the time to roll back may be past. Features from the first build have stayed into the second build,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the features that was removed in Windows 11 (I have it running here),

You can look at Widgets. You can also enter Feedback in the Feedback hub. I lost right click on Task Bar and have fed that back.

There is a new Windows 11 version out already and I expect more over time, so any registry changes you try may be removed in the first or succeeding builds.

[Live tiles gone](https://www.tomsguide.com/news/windows-11-heres-all-the-features-microsoft-just-killed#:%7E:text=Live%20Tiles%20are%20leaving.,as%20a%20Live%20Tiles%20replacement.)

> Live Tiles are leaving. Introduced with Windows 8 and ultimately
> integrated within the Start menu, Live Tiles get replaced in Windows
> 11 with a grid of app icons The new widgets feed Microsoft has
> introduced also serves as a Live Tiles replacement.

You further asked about the Start Menu suggesting it was a small sample of apps you used.

Did you see the buttons on the right side?

You can add many items to Start and then scroll through the pages. "All Apps" is still there.

[image]

Comment: They made a big deal about reintroducing the start menu in Windows 10 and now they've made it completely useless.  The Taskbar isn't big enough to pin all apps I regularly use. There's no way to pin apps to the start menus that I regularly use. It's a small sample of some randomly chosen apps.  I right click on start button and I  I use the search.  I really don't see any point to left clicking on the start menu anymore. Cortana is worthless now.  The Windows 8 UI was pretty jarring but I prefer it to this.  Small time Linux distributions have better User Interfaces.

Comment: You can pin most any App to the Start Menu. I do that here - and apps likely you might not even heard of  (DigiPLII) . Cortana was removed from the TaskBar but it is still there. Left click is there. I can do most anything you are looking for here. I adapt to things. In the Start Menu, did you see the dots on the right to see more items?